# Overflow detection and efficiency

Tags: mips

I know the `add` instruction in mips32 will do overflow detection, i.e. `add $t0, $s0, $s1`; I want to know whether this feature will make it slower than `addu $t0, $s0, $s1`, which won't detection overflow.

Clarification:

1. For *make anything faster*: I assume that overflow detection in done by hardware. Then I want to know the hardware components itself for `add`, `addu` which is faster.
2. For *Which implementation*: The book I read mention about R2000, but think the solution is an general hardware design principle, which should not be restricted to a specific version. (i.e. I think there should be some requirement that clearly state whether it should cause delay.)

Comment: How does the ALU generate an overflow signal? Does an Interrupt get generated? Or is a Test Instruction inserted into the binary-executable stream?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "make anything faster". Faster in existing implementations? Or in a theoretical implementation of addu in an ALU that doesn't support add? Or on the pipelined execution of a sequence of instructions (that could depend on overflow)? These are very different questions.

Comment: Good explanation of MIPS overflow at Stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619934/mips-overflow-detection-printing-the-result

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Thank you for pointing out sir, I want existing implementations version.

Comment: Which implementation?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I've edited it, if this my question is still problematic then I will delete it. Again thanks for pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overflow logic is just hard wired; however, the update of the flag is ignored for `addu` instruction.  The last bit just sets the update condition.

```
add: 0000 00ss ssst tttt dddd d000 0010 0000 
addu:0000 00ss ssst tttt dddd d000 0010 0001
```

There's virtually no speed difference between them.  Also, considering that the MIPS is a synchronous processor and you clock at the rate of the slowest instruction, that `add` in any form will not cause you much speed concerns.